# Google Custom Search: how to search posts in a forum?

Tags: google-custom-search

I'm not talking about the API, just manual settings.
For example, there's a bbs including several forums whose urls are like "/domain/forum-01", "/domain/forum-02"..., and each forum has its own posts, whose urls are like "/domain/post-123", "/domain/post-456". You can infer that each forum/post has a unique id that is in the url. But it cannot be inferred just from the urls that which post belongs to which forum. Now I just want to search posts in a certain forum, say, all posts in forum "/domain/forum-01",  then how should I make the Google Custom Search settings?

Comment: This question does not belongs to SO, but to [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try search string in format

```
keyword site:http://site/domain/forum
```

e.g. search for:

```
fontaine site:http://www.startrek.com/boards/star-trek-deep-space-nine
```

*UPDATE*

In case you want "site" to be fully automatic, just use Google's [Custom Search Creator](https://www.google.com/cse). You supply the site you want to search - and it generates custom search form for you.

Comment: That's not what I want: I want to make a custom search that others can use easily without typing "site:..."

Answer (score 0):

You can [Use Refinements to narrow the scope of search](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2631064).

Basically, you apply "labels" to your URL patterns. E.g.

- /domain/forum-01/* has "Label A"
- /domain/forum-02/* has "Label B"

Then these labels appear as tabs on your search results, each tab containing posts from a different forum.

Is that what you had in mind?